# How to refresh cart page when user change quantity in shopify

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I have updated the Approach now going with js I also update script and its logic and paste below do look and see if you can help me out

I wanted to display information on top of cart page according to total value in cart or number of item in cart I am working on liquid and created a Script for it just I need to manual refresh it to change according to price / items in cart I am look help to create somethings that can auto refresh page according to change in cart price / item also if there is others way that can help to display information real time with respect to cart price / item

This is code sample
"""

```
     {% if  cart.item_count == 0  %}
        <p>FREE Gift Over <span>SAR 1000</span></p>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if  cart.item_count > 99 %}
        <p>Congratulations! You've got FREE GIFT</p>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% if  cart.item_count < 8 and  cart.item_count > 0 %}
        <p>Congratulations! Youd12've got FREE GIFT</p>
      {% elsif cart.item_count < 19 and  cart.item_count >= 8 %}
        <p>Congratulations! Yodsuh45d've got FREE GIFT</p>
       
    {% endif %} 
  </div>
```

"""
Image for better understanding
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgMv.png)

The yellow part is where I want information to be

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add a [onchange event listener](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) to the quantity inputs, which update the pieces of the page you want to update, or just trigger a page reload

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I figure out something in different what if we make script run at every 5 sec so it will take data from qtn at every 5 sec and according to that it will update itself what do you think  will it work?

Comment: That will work at a technical level. But executing a function every 5 seconds is rarely a good idea. First of all because the information is wrong for X seconds, in the way I described it the information is updated instantly. Secondly you’re needlessly executing a code all the time, why not just execute it when you know you need to? Far more efficient

Comment: You are right MarshH but thing is this script will go with respect to change in qtn section and tried things to make this dependent on it but clearly it didn't work i executed  this logic also that too failed .

Answer (score 0):

Tried to convert it into js how if  we make script run at every 5 sec so it will take data from qtn at every 5 sec and according to that it will update itself what do you think will it work?
"""

```
<p id="freeGift"></p>

<script>
const time = '{{cart.item_count}}';
let greeting;
if (time == 0) {
  greeting = "FREE Gift Over SAR 1000";
} 
if (time  < 8 ) {
  greeting = "Congratulations! You've got FREE GIFT";
} else if (time < 19) {
  greeting = "Congratulations! Yodsuh45d've got FREE GIFT";
} else {
  greeting = "Congratulations!";
}
document.getElementById("freeGift").innerHTML = greeting;
</script>
```

"""

I am looking for opinion and help to execute it .